# The CSS grid shown in mobile view in desktop is different than the actual mobile view

Tags: html, css, gridview

WANT TO MAKE GRID HORIZONTAL ON ALL VIEWS.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

When considering mobile responsiveness from Google chrome mobile view it seems Horizontal.

But when checking from actual mobile its Vertical.

I want to make it everywhere 'Horizontal'[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk2pE.png),How to do that?

Comment: Not sure how you are viewing it from actual mobile but that looks like the code and example from w3schools.  when I visit their website on my iphone 7, it is still horizontal just as it is here viewed in mobile view in DevTools.

Comment: @Chris L, I checked from J1 ACE its still vertical.
Anyways using Flex-box solved the hassles of Grid view.